# Trying to publish a little bit of Javascript on the homepage AND at the bottom

Tags: php, functions

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function toggleDiv() {
    var triggeredDiv = document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv');
    if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
      triggeredDiv.classList.remove('shown');
    } else {
      triggeredDiv.classList.add('shown');
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);

  </script>
```

I need to print this little snippet of Javascript at the bottom of the homepage...

I know that I can do that using a `functions.php` command like this:

```
function for_homepage() {
    return 'JavaScript HERE';
}
add_shortcode('for_homepage', 'for_homepage');
```

And then my shortcode would be `[for_homepage]` but I don't believe that this is the best approach - I think it is better to enque the script?

Also - should I print it directly on the page (at the bottom where it needs to be for this to work) for speed reasons?

Thanks!

BTW this is to make this switcher work: https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

++++++

**UPDATE**

I believe that this might be the better approach:

```
function add_inline_script() {
  echo "<script>/* do awesome things */</script>\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_inline_script', 0 );
```

However - I would change the `wp_head` to the correct footer function...

Is this the best approach?

Comment: The best approach is to use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) where you can set dependencies and whether to use the script in the footer.

Comment: [`wp_footer` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions [is_front_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)() or [is_home](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/)() depending on what your home page is.
Also instead of wp_head you can use [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)
Your code will look something like this

```
function add_inline_script() {
    if(is_home() || is_front_page)
    wp_enqueue_script('js-handler-name', 'js-url');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_inline_script');
```